# Using a scope defined Override for a JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I am currently confronted with following Scenario:

I would like to override the equals and hashcode functions of all entities in my project and would not like to re implement the @Overrides for all Entity-classes I have. Is there a common/lnown soultion for this?

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
public class CustomJPAEntity {

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj) {
...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()  {
...
    }
```

No global fields for Entities are defined here and I want to use these Overrides in my Entity classes

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "myentity")
public class MyEntity extends CustomJPAEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "myid", nullable = false)
    private String myid;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private String requestDate;

...
```

MyEntity should take the defined @Overrides from the CustomJPAEntity instead of the standard JPA functions.
I am open for any alternative suggestions :)

My efforts so far have been to no avail.Even tried @MappedSuperclass. Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: Do you want to implement equals and hashcode for `id` field only?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: how do you reckon, your efforts are to no avail? did you try to debug into your superclass methods?

Comment: Regardless of the equals and hashcode implementation I want to achieve a way to not re-write/copy&paste my Override methods.
Overriding the methods with in every single Entity-class works fine. Debugging delivers the result given from the standard-implementation when extending the Entity.

Goal: Create one class defining the Method overrides which all Entities can derive from using exactly those overridden methods.